# what happens to spent bitcoins gained from a block of a soon to be dropped chain as a result of a fork?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, immature-coins

lets say i gained bitcoins for mining a block and then spent them on a transaction, then later the chain im using gets replaced because of a longer chain. assuming the block difference is up to where i got my spent bitcoins, what will happen to the transactions and coins i gained and spent from mining in my dropped chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all coinbase transactions are timelocked from when they are mined, so they are not spendable for a few days i believe. by that time, the block is near impossible to reverse and you can spend the new coins.

Comment: Correct, they are not mature until 100 blocks have been mined on top